# Service outage in Firebase login

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin

We are building Cordova apps using Firebase for data storage and user registration/authorization. We are getting close to launch, but are now hesistating due to problems in the Firebase Login service.

On http://status.firebase.com/ there is a summary of the availability of the Firebase Login service during the last 7 days. Yesterday the service was down for more than one hour and July 6 it was down almost an hour. Three other days during the last 7 days it has been down 10-20 minutes.

Does anyone know what uptime one should expect for the login service? In the SLA (https://www.firebase.com/terms/service-level-agreement.html) the indicated level of commitment is 99.95%, meaning less than a minute per day on average.

We are at a point where we have to make a decision about moving to something else or stay with Firebase, but before making that decision we're trying to collect more information about what uptime to expect from the Firebase Login.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: I'm sorry, I had the data right in front of me all the time. By clicking on the Login service on the status dashbord I can access more details for the Login service, http://status.firebase.com/753438

It looks like the last five days have seen an exceptional downtime in the login service. During May the uptime was 99.78% and in June it was 99.65%

Comment: So this question is not longer really valid, the data is there. We just need to decide if the uptime on Firebase Login is high enough.

Comment: [Engineer at Firebase] I'm sincerely sorry for the downtime. We've recently experiences a combination of network interrupts as well as physical hardware failures, but are actively working on / putting a lot of resources into the login service, starting with new infrastructure, and following with new feature work. Don't hesitate to reach out directly if you have questions / concerns: rob@firebase.com.

Comment: Thanks Rob, much appreciated. I will contact you via e-mail. Cheers, Markus

Comment: For the benefit of anyone looking at this issue. The work done by Firebase has drastically improved the availability of the login service. We will wait a bit more before going live to make sure uptimes continue to be good, but for now we are not looking at other alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the help in the discussions and the improvements in the service Rob!